# No video output from Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

My son's Xbox One turns on, but there is no picture. The green light and fans are working, but there's no video output. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd make sure the HDMI cable is properly connected to both the Xbox and the TV. If you still have no picture, please try to provide more details about how you have things set up, type of TV, maybe try another cable, etc.

Comment: How and to what are you connecting the xbox to?

Comment: Is your Xbox One connected to the TV using a HDMI cable? On the Xbox end, is the HDMI cable plugged to the "HDMI Out" port? Is your TV listening to the correct source (for instance, "HDMI 1", "HDMI 2", etc. depending on which HDMI port you're connected to)? Is the TV powered on, turned on, and not in standby?

Comment: Use the HDMI port that is immediately beside the power plug in the Xbox.

Answer (score 4):

The Xbox One has two HDMI ports on the back, one labelled TV IN, and one TV OUT. Make sure that the HDMI cable from your TV is connected to the TV OUT port.

Comment: Happens to me every second time I have to rewire!